# Searchkick: import scope with group clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, searchkick

I'm trying to group page fragments by kind and aggregate html content.
Here is how my search import scope looks like:

```
scope :search_import, -> {
  select("kind, string_agg(html_content, '\r\n') AS html_content")
  .group(:kind)
}
```

When I attempt to reindex records [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) uses [find_in_batches](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches) which automatically sets the order to ascending on the primary key to make the batch ordering work. This leads me to the following error: `column "page_fragments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Clearly, I can't add `id` to the group clause and I've tried to workaround this by adding `id` aggregation to the select: `COUNT (*) AS id`. However, a clear indication of a primary key `"page_fragments"."id"` in the order clause misses the alias.

The question is what possibly can be done? Looks like a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you're trying to do with your `search_import` scope? The [searchkick docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) state that it is intended to scope the records which you want to index, and thus should return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not a `group` hash.

> Searchkick uses find_in_batches to import documents. To eager load
>   associations, use the search_import scope.
>
> ...
>
> By default, all records are indexed. To control which records are
>   indexed, use the should_index? method together with the search_import
>   scope.

Comment: The idea is to change data which should be indexed. I'm trying to group page fragments by kind and concatenate their content as it was a page model. I thought it might be possible to imitate `id` for grouped records since `group` chain also responds to `find_in_batches` method.

Comment: That use case doesn't really fit with what Searchkick does. Searchkick is about indexing individual records, not grouped and concatenated data. You should look to creating/maintaining your own indexes w/ https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with creating separate model `PageFragmentAgg` and adding callbacks to `PageFragment` in order to rebuild concatenated data that should be indexed.